# Problems with the Mirror modifier

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I'm trying to make mirror effect on the x axis, and using the *Mirror Modifier*,
where I have set the pivot point in the middle of the car but it doesn't make mirror effect.

I have tried to change the orientation global, local etc - I have tried to make it with or without clipping in mirror. I have also tried with or without bisect on, using the mesh mirror interactive mirror global and local. Nothing seems to work.

My mesh is a car made from 2 intersected meshes, vertices drawn mesh from the top, and one from the side, both intersected. This is why there is no edges on one of the axis.

Can that bee part of the problem?

What have I done wrong, and how can I made mirror effect possible? I have seen a couple of tutorials (working in Blender 2.81) but haven't found a solution

[image: car body made from 2 intersected meshes]
[image: mirror modifier withot respons]

Comment: I think it needs a loop along the Y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the pivot point you are talking about, is not at the center of the mesh.
The Pivot point is the orange dot with a black outline.

To center the pivot point, go to into Object mode, select the car mesh, right click, Set Origin -> Origin to Geometry.
Then the pivot point should be centered.

Also, try deselect the Bisect for the X axis in the modifier options.

Let me hear if it worked :)

Comment: i tryed it, but there seems to be other problems, - so i put a loop a long y axis, and cut the half away, and then the mirror worked with clipping. i'm not sure what bisect does ?!

Comment: @FrankFenrizJensen I don't know either what Bisect do, but i could see you have turned it on, so i tried to recreate something like what you did and turned bisect on. It did some weird stuff, therefore i recommended you to turn it off. Also, on the picture you attached, it is very hard to see what's going on, so if you could post some more pictures from different angles or even attach the .blend file, would help a lot.